# Unique Id Generator and Randomizer

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, random, uniqueidentifier

I am trying a few items for a Secret Santa spreadsheet.

1. A Unique ID generator to print the UID in Column B for a list of names in Column A.
2. A randomizer to print the ID numbers in a random order in Column C with the restraint that Column B UID cannot equal Column C UID, ensuring no one gets themselves.
3. List Name for the random UID in Column C in Column D.

The UIDs are to start at 1 and then count until the last name receives an ID. I also want the generator to handle creating an ID for a name that is added anywhere in the list (beginning, middle, end).

I found some answers here and on other websites.
Some use complicated looping others the GUID function that I do not understand.
In general, the answers are for existing lists and not a new list with no UIDs.

I assume I would:

1. Create the UIDs and print them to Column B.
2. Save Column A and B into an array.
3. Randomize and Print the UID's into Column C.
4. Use the array to get the name for the randomized UID's in Column C and print the corresponding name in Column D.

I am unsure if this methodology is a "good" approach for this type of problem, but I would be interested in hearing other methodologies.

The only code I have so far is the row counter.

```vb
Sub secret_santa()
    
    Dim person_count As Integer
    Dim uid As Integer
       
    'Count Number of Used Rows
    person_count = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        
    'Subtract Header from person_count
    person_count = person_count - 1
       
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading correctly, you basically just want to shuffle the array whilst also imposing the constraint that no `user ID` cannot end up corresponding to itself.

There are a number of ways you can implement this. The approach below is not very generalised, can be refactored (to use more functions/subroutines) and a bit clunky. Nonetheless, it might be okay and may give you some ideas regarding implementation:

```
Option Explicit

Private Function GetArrayOfNames(ByVal someRange As Range) As Variant
    ' someRange should be a single-column, vertical range.
    Debug.Assert someRange.Columns.Count = 1
    Debug.Assert someRange.Areas.Count = 1
    Debug.Assert someRange.Rows.Count > 1

    GetArrayOfNames = someRange.Value
End Function

Private Sub SecretSantaShuffle()
    ' This procedure will overwrite the contents of the initial range,
    ' and the three columns to its right.
    Dim rangeContainingNames As Range
    Set rangeContainingNames = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A7")

    Dim inputArray() As Variant
    inputArray = GetArrayOfNames(rangeContainingNames)

    Dim rowCount As Long
    rowCount = UBound(inputArray, 1)

    ReDim Preserve inputArray(1 To rowCount, 1 To 4)

    Const NAME_COLUMN_INDEX As Long = 1
    Const UID_COLUMN_INDEX As Long = 2
    Const RANDOM_NAME_COLUMN_INDEX As Long = 3
    Const RANDOM_UID_COLUMN_INDEX As Long = 4

    Do
        Dim userIdPool As Collection
        Set userIdPool = New Collection

        Dim rowIndex As Long
        For rowIndex = LBound(inputArray, 1) To UBound(inputArray, 1)
            inputArray(rowIndex, UID_COLUMN_INDEX) = rowIndex
            userIdPool.Add rowIndex, Key:=CStr(rowIndex)
        Next rowIndex

        For rowIndex = LBound(inputArray, 1) To UBound(inputArray, 1)
            Dim randomRowIndex As Long

            Do While True
                randomRowIndex = userIdPool.Item(Application.RandBetween(1, userIdPool.Count))
                If randomRowIndex <> rowIndex Then Exit Do
                If userIdPool.Count = 1 Then Exit Do
                DoEvents
            Loop

            userIdPool.Remove CStr(randomRowIndex)

            inputArray(rowIndex, RANDOM_NAME_COLUMN_INDEX) = inputArray(randomRowIndex, NAME_COLUMN_INDEX)
            inputArray(rowIndex, RANDOM_UID_COLUMN_INDEX) = inputArray(randomRowIndex, UID_COLUMN_INDEX)
        Next rowIndex
    Loop While userIdPool.Count > 0

    rangeContainingNames.Resize(UBound(inputArray, 1), UBound(inputArray, 2)).Value = inputArray
End Sub
```

You will likely need to change what gets assigned to `rangeContainingNames`. My list of names was in range `A2:A7` of worksheet `Sheet1` but you should change the sheet name and range address to reflect the location of your names.